# How can I use Playwright to PUT multipart form-data in Python?

Tags: python, http, multipartform-data, put, playwright-python

I am trying to use Playwright to PUT multipart form-data with the Python API.
Here is the relevant [documentation](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/next/api/class-apirequestcontext#api-request-context-put).

However, it's not clear how to structure the [multipart](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/next/api/class-apirequestcontext#api-request-context-put-option-multipart) argument.
The docs say:

> ```
> multipart: Dict[str, str|float|bool|[ReadStream]|Dict] (optional)
>
>    name: str
>    File name
>
>    mimeType: str
>    File type
>
>    buffer: bytes
>    File content
> ```
>
> Provides an object that will be serialized as html form using multipart/form-data encoding and sent as this request body. If this parameter is specified content-type header will be set to multipart/form-data unless explicitly provided. File values can be passed either as [fs.ReadStream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_readstream) or as file-like object containing file name, mime-type and its content.

So, we pass it a dict with `str` keys, and either `str`, `float`, `bool`, `ReadStream` or `Dict` values. But what keys should we use? Also, how do I pass an `fs.ReadStream`, which is a JavaScript object, from a Python script? It looks like the keys should be `'name'`, `'mimeType'` and `'buffer'`. However, checking the generated HTTP request with `nc -l -p 8080` shows that a new form part is created for each key in the multipart dictionary.

I'm essentially trying to replicate the following `curl` command:

```bash
curl 'localhost:8080' -X PUT --form file='@test.zip;filename=test.zip;type=application/x-zip-compressed'
```

Assuming that you have previously run `nc -l -p 8080 | less`, you will see the following HTTP request:

```http
PUT / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 380
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------f3dde3ddff901cd3

--------------------------f3dde3ddff901cd3
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.zip"
Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed

PK^C^D
^@^@^@^@^@<D1>`xW^N<93>ESC<91>
^@^@^@
^@^@^@^H^@^\^@test.txtUT        ^@^C^Z<F7>_e^Z<F7>_eux^K^@^A^D<E8>^C^@^@^D<E8>^C^@^@Test file
PK^A^B^^^C
^@^@^@^@^@<D1>`xW^N<93>ESC<91>
^@^@^@
^@^@^@^H^@^X^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@<FF><81>^@^@^@^@test.txtUT^E^@^C^Z<F7>_eux^K^@^A^D<E8>^C^@^@^D<E8>^C^@^@PK^E^F^@^@^@^@^A^@^A^@N^@^@^@L^@^@^@^@^@
--------------------------f3dde3ddff901cd3--
```

Here is a failed attempt to achieve an equivalent HTTP request with Playwright:

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch()
    context = browser.new_context()
    page = context.new_page()

    upload_file = "test.zip"
    with open(upload_file, "rb") as file:
        response = page.request.put(
            "http://localhost:8080",
            multipart={
                "name": "file",
                "filename": upload_file,
                "mimeType": "application/x-zip-compressed",
                "buffer": file.read(),
            }
        )

    print(response)
```

This produces the following (clearly wrong) HTTP request:

```http
PUT / HTTP/1.1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/115.0.5790.24 Safari/537.36
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip,deflate,br
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarynU6IBe6rgn1KUgpw
content-length: 365
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: close

------WebKitFormBoundarynU6IBe6rgn1KUgpw
content-disposition: form-data; name="name"

file
------WebKitFormBoundarynU6IBe6rgn1KUgpw
content-disposition: form-data; name="filename"

test.zip
------WebKitFormBoundarynU6IBe6rgn1KUgpw
content-disposition: form-data; name="mimeType"

application/x-zip-compressed
------WebKitFormBoundarynU6IBe6rgn1KUgpw--
```

How can I replicate the curl HTTP request with Playwright?

Answer (score 0):

The Playwright docs are not super clear.

The structure of the `multipart` argument should be a dictionary with one key for each form part. In this case, we are only submitting a single 'part', so should only have a single key.

It is instructive to map the components of the desired multipart form submission to the Playwright multipart dictionary. For example, the following form part:

```http
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.zip"
Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed
```

maps to the following multipart dictionary:

```py
multipart={
    "file": {                   # name="file"
        "name": "test.zip",     # filename="test.zip"
        "mimeType": "application/x-zip-compressed", # Content-Type value
        "buffer": file.read(),  # binary data from file
    }
}
```

So the full example is:

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch()
    context = browser.new_context()
    page = context.new_page()

    upload_file = "test.zip"
    with open(upload_file, "rb") as file:
        response = page.request.put(
            "http://localhost:8080",
            multipart={
                "file": {
                    "name": upload_file,
                    "mimeType": "application/x-zip-compressed",
                    "buffer": file.read(),
                }
            },
        )

    print(response)
```

which produces the following HTTP request:

```http
PUT / HTTP/1.1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/115.0.5790.24 Safari/537.36
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip,deflate,br
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryK3WyngXmdiXmbBHu
content-length: 376
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: close

------WebKitFormBoundaryK3WyngXmdiXmbBHu
content-disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.zip"
content-type: application/x-zip-compressed

PK^C^D
^@^@^@^@^@<D1>`xW^N<93>ESC<91>
^@^@^@
^@^@^@^H^@^\^@test.txtUT        ^@^C^Z<F7>_e^Z<F7>_eux^K^@^A^D<E8>^C^@^@^D<E8>^C^@^@Test file
PK^A^B^^^C
^@^@^@^@^@<D1>`xW^N<93>ESC<91>
^@^@^@
^@^@^@^H^@^X^@^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^@<FF><81>^@^@^@^@test.txtUT^E^@^C^Z<F7>_eux^K^@^A^D<E8>^C^@^@^D<E8>^C^@^@PK^E^F^@^@^@^@^A^@^A^@N^@^@^@L^@^@^@^@^@
------WebKitFormBoundaryK3WyngXmdiXmbBHu--
```

Note this is not exactly the same as the curl request, but it seems close enough.